# TOP, DISTINCT, and Sub queries in Amazon Simple DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I have a Amazon SimpleDB domain with attributes "MachineName" and "TimeStamp" which logs user activity. I want to create a query that returns the latest log entry for each machine. Is this something I can do with a SimpleDB query? I'm not that proficient at regular SQL queries but I think I'd want to do something with TOP, Distinct, and/or a sub query. But non of these are supported by SimpleDB.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this query -

select * from `<domain_name>` where `TimeStamp` is not null AND `MachineName` = 'A' order by `TimeStamp` desc limit 1

Comment: No I want a list of the last log entries from each machine, not just the last log entry of the entire list.

Comment: Please try the above query and let me know.

Comment: This will return the last log entry for Machine "A", but I want the last log entry from all machines. The problem is there doesn't seem to be a way to get a list of machine names with no duplicates.

Comment: @EricAnastas Please have a look on this thread. It has all possible solution. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=78471&#78471